# Change background button color on click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 app and I have two buttons. Once I click on the first one it's color is changed, but when I click on the second one and its color is changed as well the color of the first button is not set to default. I can't access first button from the click event of the second one. How can I highlight one button and set color of another one to default on click?

**EDIT:** Here I can't access second button within the first event handler.

```
private void firstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green); 
}

private void secondButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green); 
}
```

Comment: Show your code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Please post the click events for both buttons so we may see what the problem can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you access the first button from the second one? Normally you could do something similar like this:

```
private void firstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green); 
    secondButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}

private void secondButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    firstButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}
```

And for reusability perhaps throw it in a method:

```
private void SetButtonColor(Button toDefaultColor, Button toGreenColor)
{
    toGreenColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    toDefaultColor.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
}

private void secondButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetButtonColor(firstButton, (sender as Button));
}
```